# Accessing data over hadoop? A step by step explanation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to understand each and every step that happens when data needs to get accessed over HDFS. Where can I find a step by step explanation of a write/read operation on HDFS.

I am well aware of the fact that the namenode contains filesystem specific metadata. But I want to know exactly what is the data which is stored on the namenode. Here is my guess at it:
As individual datanodes update the namenode with the block information for respective blocks hosted by them, when they boot up, the namenode just has the filename(with the full directory structure) with the block numbers at which the data for that file is stored at. Whenever a read/write comes in it writes/reads the block numbers from the namenode and approaches the datanodes according to the reverse mapping stored in-memory by the namenode (the map was constructed and updated by the data nodes when they came up) which tells the file operationn that what block number is hosted by which data node and therefore which are the data nodes which it needs to write/read information to/from. This is just a guess and wish if someone could confirm on this. Also, is this the way in which mappers read from the files which is specified as input to a map reduce job , the only difference being job tracker may perform the job of figuring out the data nodes and spawning the mappers on the corresponding data nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I find a step by step explanation of a write/read operation on HDFS.

Check [this](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-zw6KHOtbT4MmRkZWJjYzEtYjI3Ni00NTFjLWE0OGItYTU5OGMxYjc0N2M1/edit?pli=1) comic for reading/writing data from HDFS. It doesn't deal with the API level detail, but describe at a high level. Also, [this](http://www.aosabook.org/en/hdfs.html) article on HDFS is interesting.

> I am well aware of the fact that the namenode contains filesystem specific metadata. But I want to know exactly what is the data which is stored on the namenode.

It's possible to take an offline dump of the HDFS metadata contents using these [instructions](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/hdfs/r0.21.0/hdfs_imageviewer.html).

Comment: This is really useful especially the comic!! :)